# What is the right configuration of titan db 1.0 running against ES deployed on google/aws cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

I'm using titan 1.0 with ES 1.51 running internally as a service (127.0.0.1), and it is working pretty well.

My working ES configuration is :

```
    storage.backend=cassandra
    storage.hostname=cassandraserver2-cassandra-00

    cache.db-cache = true
    cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
    cache.db-cache-time = 180000
    cache.db-cache-size = 0.25
    query.fast-property=true

    index.search.backend=elasticsearch
    index.search.hostname=localhost
    index.search.elasticsearch.interface=NODE
```

Now I want to redeploy the ES into the cloud , but unfortunately titan isn't up.

The exception  i get is:

```
    gremlin> tg = TitanFactory.open('../conf/titan-db.properties')
    Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
    Display stack trace? [yN] y
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:460)
        at com.t...
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:198)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.execute(InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.java:86)
```

What is the right configuration of titan properties to run against elasticsearch service on google/aws cloud ??

suppose the external ip of the "VM" is 8.35.193.69 and i reach this machine with ping

I'm using titan-db properties:

```
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.hostname=cassandraserver2-cassandra-00

cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.25
query.fast-property=true

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=8.35.193.69
index.search.client-only=true
index.search.local-mode=false
index.search.elasticsearch.interface=NODE
```

any solutions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure port `9300` is open on your instance. If it's not open, you need to:

1. Ensure ES service is up `sudo service elasticsearch status`
2. Ensure port `9300` is open and accepting requests. Check how [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/309052/check-if-port-is-open-or-closed-on-a-linux-server)

If the port is closed, you need to enable TCP transport communication. Check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html)

Change your configuration to look like this:

```
# elasticsearch config
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.elasticsearch.interface=TRANSPORT_CLIENT
index.search.hostname=your_ip:9300
```

Comment: @MTA the port is up , i've tested before. I think maybe some of the properties is missing, is my titan configuration file ok ?

Comment: @MTA it doesn't works too , by the way , when we use TRANSPORT_CLIENT mode in ES ?

Comment: You use it when Elasticsearch is a service and you're connecting to it remotely.

Comment: @VitalyTarasiuk Are you sure your firewalls allow connections to ports 9300 and 9200?

Comment: @MTA: something strange happened i  change back index.search.elasticsearch.interface=NODE , and it connected successfully, but when i create external indexes with titan no data updated into ES service on the cloud .....hmmm

Comment: When you use put the interface value as NODE, you probably ask titan to create an internally managed elasticsearch instance. When you use TRANSPORT_CLIENT, it asks titan to connect yo an external service. Does that make any sense to you? Does it help understand why that happened?

Comment: @MTA - thanks for explaining , what about  -->  index.search.client-only=true ; 
index.search.local-mode=false  ?? need i this to the cloud configuration ?

Comment: @MTA : As you said i need the TRANSPORT_CLIENT , changed back the conf file , and still no response from ES service ( the server VM and the ES cluster VM on the same google region) . This is output from ES VM /n
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9300            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                                    
elasticsearch$ ......seems the port is open on both sides